# Can I add more than one Google account under My Logins?

Tags: support, login

I have one Stack Exchange account (se1) and two Google accounts (ga1 and ga2). I signed up creating se1, later I added ga1 to my logins, but when I try to add ga2 to my logins, the page doesn't redirect for authentication, but instead back to my profile page.

Is there any way to add a second Google account to my login list?

I would like to have the three logins, and only one account.

Comment: Aren't google accounts meant to refer to a unique personality, when logging in? Are you trying to create a sock puppet or what?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The OP is trying to add a second google account to their login list, not create a second account from the second google account.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have all three logins. I don't want more stack exchange accounts. Just one account with three logins. Is that possible?

Comment: I have been messing with this. Now I have two accounts one with se1 and ga1 logins and one with ga2 login. May I merge them?

Comment: There's a help center article for merging: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts I don't know if it will work with two Google accounts, since you're having trouble adding a second Google account to begin with.

Comment: Not a problem. You may want to clarify your question more, because I believe the downvoters are probably reading it as you want to create multiple accounts here. For instance, _"the page doesn't ask me for the account"_ could be reworded to _"the page doesn't redirect for authentication, but instead back to my profile page."_ Your title could also be changed to _"Can I add more than one Google account under My Logins?"_ as it's unclear whether or not you can in the first place, and this is the question you're really asking in the post itself.

Comment: Thanks again @Kendra, I reworded my question as you suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes, you can indeed add two Google accounts to your my logins.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159786/does-add-more-logins-not-work-or-is-it-misleading/159832#159832)

The problem here was not a restriction, it was the fact that you were *already logged into Google* with the first of the two accounts, and Stack Exchange assumed that was the account you meant.

There are two ways to get around this issue, one using an extra credintial (which you have) and one using Google only.

Extra credintial:

First, if you haven't already, add a second method of logging in to your account. If you already have one, then you're all set here. After that's taken care of, you'll want to go to Google and sign out with the account that is already on your Stack Exchange logins. Sign back into Google with the second Google account, then sign into Stack Exchange (if you aren't already) with your second method of logging in. Now when you go to add your login, it will attempt to add the Google account you are currently logged into. Give permissions, and you should be good to go.

Google Only:

Go to your [Google settings dashboard.](https://www.google.com/settings/) In the top right corner will be your username and a small arrow. Click that to open a menu. You should see a button that reads "Add Account" at the bottom of the box that pops up. Click this and add the second Google account. From here, attempt to add a new login as usual. Be sure you select the correct account when given the option.

If both of these methods fail, you should contact support using the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page, as there may be something wrong with your account, such as a second account already created with the second Google account that isn't merging properly.

If one of these methods creates a second account for you, you can merge the two by following the process outlined in [the help center.](https://stackoverflow.com/help-center/merging-accounts)

Comment: Extra credential didn'd work, It takes me to "Switch Users on Stack Overflow" page. It says "you can log in as <real user name1> or stay logged in as <real user name2>. I tried that before you posted your answer but didn't work, I tried it now again and it didn't work either

Comment: Google "Add Account" didn't work either. I already tried it before posting my question.

Comment: The contact form you provided on the comments section worked indeed. I have the accounts merged now. Thank you very much.

Comment: if you add an answer with the link you provided on the comments, I will mark it as the accepted answer. Obviously I cannot mark your comment as the accepted answer.

Comment: @JesúsLópez I've added that link and information to this answer to make it more comprehensive- Since it's what happened in your case, I should have added it to begin with honestly.

Comment: why do you mean by "merge"? I don't want to have only one account. I would like to have two accounts, but beign able to easier switch between them?

Comment: @Serge Well, then your question that I was commenting on is very misleading. If you merge two accounts, you will only have one account but be able to log on to that account with multiple Google logins. If you're wanting two _separate_ SO accounts, then there's not a super easy way to switch between them. You would have to log out of SO (the button for this is up in the top bar, under the Stack Exchange menu) then log in using the credentials of the other account.

Comment: @Serge Be sure that if you _do_ use two SO accounts, you do not use them incorrectly, i.e. to upvote your own posts, upvote other posts multiple times, target someone, etc. Doing any of these will quickly get you a temporary suspension and get your second account deleted. So be careful when using two SO accounts.

Comment: my question was really about two separate accounts. If you are under a Google account, then is more complicated: log out of first account, log out of Google account, log-in with other google account, finally log-in with SO

Comment: @Serge Yet your question read as asking how to add two separate Google accounts to one single SO account. (That's the use of the "Add Login" feature.) The way you're talking here is you want _two_ SO accounts, one for each Google account. If that is the case, you need to go edit your question to reflect this. If not, then I feel like you're misunderstanding something somewhere (or I am misunderstanding you somewhere), but I'm not sure where.